# How to modify the condition for a LINQ request to remove users that are in another table?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ request that get data about the users that are present in the Appointments table

```
var patients = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Appointments.Any(a => a.DoctorId == doctorId))
```

Now I need to modify this condition, not to take those users who fell into the black list. Now I need to modify this condition, not to take those users who fell into the black list. In another place, I take them as follows:

```
var banned = _context.DoctorBlackLists.Where(x => x.DoctorId == doctorId)
```

How I'm in one query to combine these conditionі, get the users that are in the table Appointments, except those that are present in the table DoctorBlackLists?
Both tables, Appointments and DoctorBlackLists, have a column DoctorId and UserId, its associated with the Users table

Comment: I think you said it yourself: one List [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) the other (if the two Lists contain the same source object, a `List<[User]>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could create a list of banned user ids:

```
var bannedUserIds = _context.DoctorBlackLists
                       .Where(x => x.DoctorId == doctorId)
                       .Select(x => x.UserId)
                       .ToList();
```

And use it (check that the patient is not in a banned list):

```
var patients =     _context.Users.Where(x => 
                       !bannedUserIds.Contains(x.Id)
                       && x.Appointments.Any(a => a.DoctorId == doctorId))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer! I was writing the same answer but in the mean you have posted it! :)

Comment: Have a small correction! Guess it! Or should I post as a answer :)

Comment: Yes! You got it! Thank you.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Calling of `.ToList()` will execute the query however OP hasn't specified whether he wants to execute the query right away or a bit later. So it depends